# How many Matrices of size 3 by 3 have a determinant of 1?

Tags: matrices

Suppose you had a matrix where each index goes from a natural value of 0 - 25 ([The Hill Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) Algorithm uses 3 by 3 matrices where each numeric value corresponds to a letter)

Given a matrix of size 3 by 3 with each index corresponding to a number from 0 - 25 how can I determine how many matrices will have a determinant of 1 in this case?

Comment: That sounds very difficult to compute. Fortunately, you seem to have missed a couple of details in the Wikipedia link: (1) The matrices work modulo 26, and so their determinant should be computed modulo 26 too; (2) we're looking not necessarily for matrices of determinant $1$ but merely for _invertible_ matrices. Both of these ought to make the counting a lot easier.

Comment: To start with, we should probably use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find the count for matrices modulo 2 and modulo 13 separately, and then simply multiply those counts afterwards. How to [count invertible matrices modulo a prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields) is well known.

Comment: So I made a program to do this and my computer is still computing..

Comment: @Nikunj I'm surprised a formula for figuring out total possible determinants for a finite set of indexes for n * n matrices doesn't exist

Comment: @BDillan you underestimate the power of brute force!(Do you want  to see the very inefficient code?)

Comment: @Nikunj: How long does it take to compute (assuming the corrections in my first comment) $(2^3-1)(2^3-2)(2^2-2^2)(13^3-1)(13^3-13)(13^3-13^2)$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm well that's 0. ($2^2-2^2$) and I'd like to ask how did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: @Nikunj: Oops, that should have been $(2^3-2^2)$ of course. It's the [formula for counting elements of $GL(2,2)$ times $GL(2,13)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well I was unaware of that so I tried to do it by brute force, which wasn't a very good idea. (and thank you for the link)